# How to use Boost XML Parser

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I have written an XML parser for reading an XML file and convert it to an object of my "Position" class. It works fine. Please take a look at its code below.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="15">
<position class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <Degrees>1</Degrees>
    <Minutes>2</Minutes>
    <Seconds>3</Seconds>
    <data class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Degrees>1</Degrees>
        <Minutes>2</Minutes>
        <Seconds>3</Seconds>
    </data>
</position>
</boost_serialization>
```

Position Class:

```
#ifndef XMLMANAGER_POSITION_H
#define XMLMANAGER_POSITION_H

#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>

class Data
{
public:
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
    }
};
class Position
{

public:
    // every serializable class needs a constructor
    Position() {
        Degrees = 0;
        Minutes = 0;
        Seconds = 0;
    };
    Position(int degrees, int minutes, float seconds){
        Degrees = degrees;
        Minutes = minutes;
        Seconds = seconds;
    };
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
    Data data;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(data);
    }
};

#endif //XMLMANAGER_POSITION_H
```

main Function:

```
    // Load an Object from XML
    std::ifstream ifs("/tests/r.karimi/XmlManager/data/Output.xml");
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive ixa(ifs);
    Position newPosition;
    try
    {
        ixa >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(newPosition);
    }
    catch (std::exception const &ex)
    {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Degree " << newPosition.Degrees <<
              " Minutes " << newPosition.Minutes <<
              " Seconds " << newPosition.Seconds << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Degree " << newPosition.data.Degrees <<
              " Minutes " << newPosition.data.Minutes <<
              " Seconds " << newPosition.data.Seconds << std::endl;
```

Now, I want to pasre the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="15">
<position class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <Degrees>0</Degrees>
    <Minutes>0</Minutes>
    <Seconds>0.000000000e+00</Seconds>
    <data class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Degrees>1</Degrees>
        <Minutes>2</Minutes>
        <Seconds>3</Seconds>
    </data>
    <data class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Degrees>4</Degrees>
        <Minutes>5</Minutes>
        <Seconds>6</Seconds>
    </data>
</position>
</boost_serialization>
```

What should I do? I have tried different solution such as get an array of "Data" class in "Position" class, but it does not work. I prefer to use Boost library for my project. (Unless it is not possible!!!)

Comment: Q. "How to use Boost XML parser?" A. "First, you write one; next, you propose it; next it gets accepted; then you use it"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost does **not** have an XML library.

Boost Serialization doesn't read general XML (like) documents. It reads XML archives **only**. Meaning, you don't control the XML.

That all said, you can simply extend the class with another Data member, and it would *accidentally* result in a very similar XML archive. Perhaps this is good enough for you:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a1187e3585d1779)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

class Data
{
public:
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
    }
};

class Position
{

public:
    // every serializable class needs a constructor
    Position() {
        Degrees = 0;
        Minutes = 0;
        Seconds = 0;
    };
    Position(int degrees, int minutes, float seconds){
        Degrees = degrees;
        Minutes = minutes;
        Seconds = seconds;
    };
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
    Data data;
    Data data2;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", data);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", data2);
    }
};

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    Position position;
    position.Degrees = 1;
    position.Minutes = 2;
    position.Seconds = 3;
    position.data = {1,2,3};
    position.data2 = {4,5,6};

    {
        std::ofstream ofs("output.xml");
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);

        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(position);
    }
}
```

Writes

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="14">
<position class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <Degrees>1</Degrees>
    <Minutes>2</Minutes>
    <Seconds>3.000000000e+00</Seconds>
    <data class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <Degrees>1</Degrees>
        <Minutes>2</Minutes>
        <Seconds>3.000000000e+00</Seconds>
    </data>
    <data>
        <Degrees>4</Degrees>
        <Minutes>5</Minutes>
        <Seconds>6.000000000e+00</Seconds>
    </data>
</position>
</boost_serialization>
```

### UPDATE

If you DIDN'T want to control the XML, all the better. Just let the library do what you want it to do:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6088ece005868bbe)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>

class Data
{
public:
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
    }
};

class Position
{

public:
    // every serializable class needs a constructor
    Position() {
        Degrees = 0;
        Minutes = 0;
        Seconds = 0;
    };
    Position(int degrees, int minutes, float seconds){
        Degrees = degrees;
        Minutes = minutes;
        Seconds = seconds;
    };
    int Degrees;
    int Minutes;
    float Seconds;
    std::vector<Data> data;

private:
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int /*version*/){
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Degrees);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Minutes);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(Seconds);
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("data", data);
    }
};

#include <fstream>

int main() {
    {
        Position position;
        position.Degrees = 1;
        position.Minutes = 2;
        position.Seconds = 3;
        position.data = { {1,2,3}, {4,5,6 } };

        std::ofstream ofs("output.xml");
        boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);

        oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(position);
    }
    {
        std::ifstream ifs("output.xml");
        boost::archive::xml_iarchive ia(ifs);

        Position position;
        ia >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(position);
    }
}
```

In this case, the XML *happens* to look like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<!DOCTYPE boost_serialization>
<boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="14">
<position class_id="0" tracking_level="0" version="0">
    <Degrees>1</Degrees>
    <Minutes>2</Minutes>
    <Seconds>3.000000000e+00</Seconds>
    <data class_id="1" tracking_level="0" version="0">
        <count>2</count>
        <item_version>0</item_version>
        <item class_id="2" tracking_level="0" version="0">
            <Degrees>1</Degrees>
            <Minutes>2</Minutes>
            <Seconds>3.000000000e+00</Seconds>
        </item>
        <item>
            <Degrees>4</Degrees>
            <Minutes>5</Minutes>
            <Seconds>6.000000000e+00</Seconds>
        </item>
    </data>
</position>
</boost_serialization>
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice and comprehensive answer. But reading from XML is more important to me. How can I load it to my object?

Comment: Can I define two members or an array? If not, what should I do?

Comment: Erm. Maybe I'm missing something: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d612ca1776785ce

Comment: You should be using Boost Serialization if you want to serialize your class. If you want to serialize a class containing an array of Data, do that. If you want to serialize a class containing a vector or list or map of Data, do **that**. Don't think about the XML, because it's Boost Serialization's job to do that. It's an _implementation detail_.

Comment: See the **UPDATE** section in my answer for [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6088ece005868bbe)

Comment: I link to freaking live examples ([twice, even](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6088ece005868bbe)). How can you claim it doesn't compile? Take note of the includes, please.

Comment: Relevant [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/serialization/doc/tutorial.html#stl). Or, if you are just left scratching your head: [How can I serialize an std::vector with boost::serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276203/how-can-i-serialize-an-stdvector-with-boostserialization)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149887/discussion-between-reza-and-sehe).

Comment: Can you give me an example of TinyXML library which do this. Everything I have seen so far is to parse XML and fill out the object manually. I want to do it automatically by something like operator<<

Comment: You're looking for a magic bullet? It got eaten by a unicorn. Here's a hint: you can implement `operator<<` for your types in C++.

Comment: I don't want to reinvent the wheel ! I want something like Boost library. I have my class object and also my xml. Only read the XML and fill in the object. That's it

Comment: You're reinventing the wheel because your team members are using "faux boost serialization" archive format. Tell them to not do that.

Comment: You mean it's not possible to do it with any library :-|

Comment: I told you what I meant. See http://paste.ubuntu.com/25154490/ (`sudo apt-get install libpugixml-dev; g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -lpugixml -o test`). See the [output](http://i.imgur.com/rogf9El.png)